# VBA Is it possible to create a conditionaly formatted table that automatically updates itsself?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a sheet I am trying to build on excel where I am creating multiple tables (the amount is variable so it can be anywhere from 5 tables to 65 tables), which I have been able to do. I am now trying to conditionally format the tables created to highlight cells based on simple conditions (if cell 1 equals "Available" and cell 2 (date format) is less than a week away, highlight row red. If cell 1 is equal to "Handed In", Highlight Row Grey there are a few more very similar to this but the conditions to be highlighted do not change.

An example of a manually created table is shown in the image below:
[image: example output]

As you can see in the image, the columns numbers and row numbers are variable, however i don't see this being a problem.

Currently, all I can find is VBA code that you have to run every time and it will update the table ([see here](https://www.educba.com/vba-conditional-formatting/)). However **I essentially want to create code that will do the manual typing in of all the conditions in the tablefor me into the condition manager. Simply put, I want to do this:**

[image: Conditionally formatting Rules manager]

Comment: Record a macro while adding the conditions and use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub VBAformatting()
  Dim rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
  Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition

  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'Please put here your sheet
  Set rng = sh.Range("A1:A10")
  'if the reange is already conditional formated:
   rng.FormatConditions.Delete

   Set cond1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=A1=""Available""")
   Set cond2 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(A1=""Handed In"",B1>3)")

   'Defining and setting the format to be applied for each condition
   With cond1
     .Font.Color = vbWhite
     .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
     .Font.Bold = True
     .Font.Italic = True
     .SetFirstPriority
   End With

   With cond2
    .Font.Color = vbBlue
    .Font.Bold = True
   End With
End Sub
```